# Make parent container fitted inner content

Tags: html, css

I have this layout [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oblomov86/PyB4t/).

```
<a>
<span class="blue">111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111</span>
<span class="red">111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111</span>
</a>

span {
    display: inline-block;
}
.red{
    background-color:red;
}
.blue{
    background-color:blue;
}
a {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:green;
}
```

I want to make parent anchor fitted to width of inner spans for responsive behaviour during resizing. How?

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: block` on `span`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PyB4t/1/)

```
span {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: But I want spans can render in one line during resizinng.

Comment: @oblomov Basically, if you remove display:inline-block from `a` tag, the parent container still fitted the inner content. Try to remove the background color of red and blue to see it - http://jsfiddle.net/PyB4t/8/

Comment: Table layout is not good idea for me (but it works good). I've removed inline-block from anchor's css, it works, thank you. But now I have another problem: in case of text in the second line is gerater than text in first line I need the equal widths for both lines.